# WoW Macro for several SendChatMessage()

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to broadcast a message throughout several channels. When left click, broadcasting to all channels, when right click, just to channel 1. This is my original script, though it exceeds the character limits of a macro. How can I make it shorter?

```
/run s="a long long long long .... message ..."
/script SendChatMessage(s ,"CHANNEL" , "COMMON" ,"1");
/script if(GetMouseButtonClicked()=="LeftButton") then SendChatMessage(s ,"CHANNEL" , "COMMON" ,"4") end;
/script if(GetMouseButtonClicked()=="LeftButton") then SendChatMessage(s ,"CHANNEL" , "COMMON" ,"7") end;
```

I was looking for how to use "`for each (4,7)`" to replace the last 2 lines, but didn't find a "`for each`" syntax for WoW API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each exists, but only if you create an array first, which isn't helpful. I can't log in to check right now, but you can try something like this:

Make one macro that makes it act like you clicked on a button and reroutes to another based on right/left click:

```
/click [button:1] MultiBarLeftButton2; MultiBarLeftButton3
```

Then make two macros for each separate thing and put them on the proper button location. So, for the left click:

```
/csay 4 yourmessage
/csay 7 yourmessage
```

and right click:

```
/csay 1 yourmessage
```

If your message is too long to fit, you should be able to use semicolons to keep it all on one line:

```
/csay 4 yourmessage; 7 yourmessage
```

Or, you can do part of it, and put `/click MultiBarLeftButton4` to chain it to another button with the rest of the message.

For reference, here's the different action bar names:

```
ActionButton#                Main Bar*
BonusActionButton#           Dynamic bar that switches actions based on Druid Forms, Warrior Stances, and Rogue Stealth*
MultiBarBottomLeftButton#    Bottom Left Bar
MultiBarBottomRightButton#   Bottom Right Bar
MultiBarRightButton#         Right Bar
MultiBarLeftButton#          Right Bar 2 (to the left of "Right Bar")
PetActionButton#             Pet Bar
ShapeshiftButton#            Druid Forms, Paladin Auras, Warrior Stances, Death Knight Presences, Rogue Stealth
```

[Here's](http://www.wowpedia.org/Making_a_macro#Macro_Branching_with_.2Fclick) a quick reference on branching with /click.